# How to apply binomial GLMM (glmer) to percentages rather than yes-no counts?

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have a repeated-measures experiment where the dependent variable is a percentage, and I have multiple factors as independent variables. I'd like to use `glmer` from the R package `lme4` to treat it as a logistic regression problem (by specifying `family=binomial`) since it seems to accommodate this setup directly.

My data looks like this:

```
 > head(data.xvsy)
   foldnum      featureset noisered pooldur dpoolmode       auc
 1       0         mfcc-ms      nr0       1      mean 0.6760438
 2       1         mfcc-ms      nr0       1      mean 0.6739482
 3       0    melspec-maxp    nr075       1       max 0.8141421
 4       1    melspec-maxp    nr075       1       max 0.7822994
 5       0 chrmpeak-tpor1d    nr075       1       max 0.6547476
 6       1 chrmpeak-tpor1d    nr075       1       max 0.6699825
```

and here's the R command that I was hoping would be appropriate:

```
 glmer(auc~1+featureset*noisered*pooldur*dpoolmode+(1|foldnum), data.xvsy, family=binomial)
```

The problem with this is that the command complains about my dependent variable not being integers:

```
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

and the analysis of this (pilot) data gives weird answers as a result.

I understand why the `binomial` family expects integers (yes-no counts), but it seems it should be OK to regress percentage data directly. How to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem OK to me, as 5 out of 10 isn't the same information as 500 out of 1000. Express the response as one count of the no. "successes" & one count of the no. "failures".

Comment: @Scortchi thanks, I think you may be right. I was thinking in part about the continuous nature of my percentages (derived from probabilistic decisions) similar to this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77376/generalized-linear-models-with-continuous-proportions but I believe I can express my data via a meaningful conversion to integer counts.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to use a vector of proportions as the response variable with `glmer(., family = binomial)`, you need to set the number of trials that led to each proportion using the `weights` argument.  For example, using the `cbpp` data from the `lme4` package:

```
glmer(incidence / size ~ period + (1 | herd), weights = size,
   family = binomial, data = cbpp)
```

If you do not know the total number of trials, then a binomial model is not appropriate, as is indicated in the error message.

Comment: I can't say whether using weights for this works or not. But you certainly can input the data as a two column matrix (successes/failures) on the left hand side of the formula.

Comment: But @ndoogan, the original question was about proportions, not successes/failures.  And the above code does work, as I took it from the `cbpp` help page.

Comment: Fair enough. Though, I intended to mean successes/failures (*not* intended to be division) is where the proportions for a binomial model come from.

Comment: +1 but readers might want to see @BenBolker's answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189115 about possible ways to deal with overdispersion.

Answer (score 10):

If your response is a proportion, percentage or anything similiar that can only take values in $(0,1)$ you would typically use beta regression, not the binomial one.

Comment: A binomial model is a model of proportions. Though, it's only appropriate when you know the number of trials. If all you have is a percent with no indication of the number of trials, then I believe you are correct that beta regression is appropriate.

Comment: @ndoogan To clarify, my advice is not "use beta regression when your response is a proportion" but rather "if your response can only take values in $(0,1)$ _such as_ proportions/percentages then beta regression is typical"

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point. I'm accepting the other answer because it answers the question as written, but the point about beta regression is well made so I've upvoted it.