# Probability curve for glmm

Tags: r, probability, data-visualization, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have some rather basic questions that I suspect I know the answer to but would like to confirm.

I have a simple experiment measuring the number of a certain insect growth stage in the proportional presence of a dietary treatment. I have modeled the data using a binomial glmm. I would now like to plot a probability curve of the fixed effect (Treatment) using the `sjPlot` package. Following [this tutorial](http:///http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.glmer/), I am using `"fe.slope"` as the plot type. However, in the tutorial the y-axis is numbered from 0 - 1, as befits a probability curve, whereas my y-axis has a proportional scale from 0% - 100%. I assume it has something to do with the proportional aspect of my glmm. Can I simply  change the y-axis scale manually to go from 0 - 1 without affecting the nature of the plot?
Further, my Treatments are named 'T1, T2, T3, T4 and T5', yet the x-axis is labelled 0 - 4. Can I also manually change these without affecting the plot's true meaning?
Finally, what do the points on this plot represent? Are they residuals?

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)

df<-as.data.frame(df)

df$OLRE <- seq_len(nrow(df)) #create observation level random effect

df[,2:3] %<>% lapply(function(x) as.integer(x)) #change to integers

m1<-glmer(Stage/Total~Treatment + (1|OLRE), data=df, family='binomial',weights=Total)

sjp.glmer(m1, type = "fe.slope",show.ci=TRUE)
```

**Data:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Treatment = c("0_diatoms", "0_diatoms", "0_diatoms", 
"25_diatoms", "25_diatoms", "25_diatoms", "50_diatoms", "50_diatoms", 
"50_diatoms", "75_diatoms", "75_diatoms", "75_diatoms", "100_diatoms", 
"100_diatoms", "100_diatoms"), Stage = c(45L, 50L, 50L, 58L, 
40L, 72L, 31L, 45L, 40L, 63L, 61L, 50L, 23L, 33L, 30L), Total = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100), OLRE = 1:15), .Names = c("Treatment", "Stage", "Total", 
"OLRE"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why do you divide Stage by Total when deriving your outcome variable and also including Total in the weights= option of your model? In other words, what is it that you are trying to model? What does Stage represent, what does Total represent and what does OLRE represent?

Comment: Hi @IsabellaGhement, thanks for the comment. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189115/fitting-a-binomial-glmm-glmer-to-a-response-variable-that-is-a-proportion-or-f), which has the same design as mine. OLRE refers to observation level random effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot you produced doesn't make sense for your data, since Treatment is supposed to be a categorical variable (not an integer variable as per your plot).

I would re-fit the model by forcing Treatment to be a factor.  I think OLRE should be a factor too - usually, the random effect goes hand in hand with a grouping variable (i.e., a factor in R's parlance).

So maybe try something like this:

```
df$Outcome <- df$Stage/df$Total

df$Treatment <- factor(df$Treatment)

df$OLRE <- factor(df$OLRE)


m1 <- glmer(Outcome ~ Treatment + (1|OLRE), data=df,
            family='binomial',weights=Total)


set.seed(17)

p1 <- sjp.glmer(m1, type = "pred.fe", vars = c("Treatment"), 
                show.ci = FALSE, show.scatter=FALSE)
p1

p2 <- sjp.glmer(m1, type = "pred", vars = c("Treatment"), 
                show.ci = FALSE, show.scatter=FALSE)
p2
```

According to the help file for sjp.glmer, which is available at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.4.0/topics/sjp.glmer, the options `type = "pred.fe"` and `"type = "pred"` will help plot the predicted values against the response, with the predicted values being derived only from the fixed effects (for `type = "pred.fe"`) or conditional on random intercept (for `"type = "pred"`).

The beauty with saving the two plots is that you can then inspect the output produced by R when typing the plot names and "steal" that output to create your own customized graph.  For example, the output for the plot p1 is as follows:

```
> p1
$data
x            y ci.low ci.high resp.y grp
1  1 0.4832236     NA      NA   0.45   1
2  1 0.4832236     NA      NA   0.50   1
3  1 0.4832236     NA      NA   0.50   1
4  3 0.5684214     NA      NA   0.58   1
5  3 0.5684214     NA      NA   0.40   1
6  3 0.5684214     NA      NA   0.72   1
7  4 0.3855458     NA      NA   0.31   1
8  4 0.3855458     NA      NA   0.45   1
9  4 0.3855458     NA      NA   0.40   1
10 5 0.5807438     NA      NA   0.63   1
11 5 0.5807438     NA      NA   0.61   1
12 5 0.5807438     NA      NA   0.50   1
13 2 0.2850919     NA      NA   0.23   1
14 2 0.2850919     NA      NA   0.33   1
15 2 0.2850919     NA      NA   0.30   1

$plot

attr(,"class")
[1] "sjPlot"        "sjpglm.ppresp"
Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

So the component `p1$data` of the plot gives you access to the data used to create the plot.

For example, for your first treatment,0_diatoms, you can compute the predicted probability by hand as follows and compare it against the one produced by sjp.glmer for `type = "pred.fe"`:

```
intercept <- summary(m1)$coeff["(Intercept)","Estimate"]

exp(intercept)/(1 + exp(intercept))
```

The probability comes out to be 0.4832236 and this is listed under `p1$data` (in the column titled y) for each of the three observations corresponding to the first treatment group (i.e., 0_diatoms).  The observations themselves are listed under the column titled resp.y of `p1$data.`

For the second treatment, the predicted probability computed by hand would be:

```
intercept <- summary(m1)$coeff["(Intercept)","Estimate"]

slope25_diatoms <- summary(m1)$coeff["Treatment25_diatoms","Estimate"]

exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms)/(1 + exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms))
```

hence  0.5684214.  This is listed under the column y in `p$data` for each of the observations in your 25_diatoms treatment group.

The predicted probabilities for the first two treatment groups that are produced by sjp.glmer with the option `type="pred"` can be replicated by hand with the commands below:

```
intercept <- summary(m1)$coeff["(Intercept)","Estimate"]

ranef(m1)$OLRE[1, ]
ranef(m1)$OLRE[2, ]
ranef(m1)$OLRE[3, ]

exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[1, ])/
  (1 + exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[1, ]))

exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[2, ])/
  (1 + exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[2, ]))

exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[3, ])/
  (1 + exp(intercept + ranef(m1)$OLRE[3, ]))
```

and

```
intercept <- summary(m1)$coeff["(Intercept)","Estimate"]

slope25_diatoms <- summary(m1)$coeff["Treatment25_diatoms","Estimate"]

exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[4, ])/
 (1 + exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[4, ]))

exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[5, ])/
 (1 + exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[5, ]))

exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[6, ])/
 (1 + exp(intercept + slope25_diatoms + ranef(m1)$OLRE[6, ]))
```

These probabilities come out to be 0.4646612,  0.492606 and 0.492606 for the first treatment (i.e., 0_diatoms) and 0.5748393, 0.4744047 and 0.6512543 for the second treatment (i.e., 25_diatoms).  You will recognize then in the first 6 rows of column y contained in the R output corresponding to `p2$data`:

```
> p2$data
x            y ci.low ci.high resp.y grp
1  1 0.4646612     NA      NA   0.45   1
2  1 0.4926060     NA      NA   0.50   1
3  1 0.4926060     NA      NA   0.50   1
4  3 0.5748393     NA      NA   0.58   1
5  3 0.4744047     NA      NA   0.40   1
6  3 0.6512543     NA      NA   0.72   1
7  4 0.3447117     NA      NA   0.31   1
8  4 0.4209869     NA      NA   0.45   1
9  4 0.3934527     NA      NA   0.40   1
10 5 0.6078542     NA      NA   0.63   1
11 5 0.5968777     NA      NA   0.61   1
12 5 0.5358618     NA      NA   0.50   1
13 2 0.2574995     NA      NA   0.23   1
14 2 0.3081921     NA      NA   0.33   1
15 2 0.2927040     NA      NA   0.30   1
```

The above should provide enough insight into what sjp.glmer is actually plotting to enable you to generate your own plots.  In particular, you can plot the predicted probabilities on the 0 to 1 scale (rather then converting them to percentage points, as sjp.glmer does).  You can also force sjp.glmer to return uncertainty intervals around the predicted probability by using the `show.ci = TRUE` option.

I am not sure why sjp.glmer jitters the response values in the column resp.y before plotting them when you include the option `show.scatter=TRUE`. I would have thought that using `show.scatter=FALSE` would have turned off the random jittering, but it actually removes the response observations altogether from the plot. So either use `set.seed(17)` (or some other random seed) before creating the plot and then invoke the option `show.scatter=TRUE` for sjp.glmer, or create your own plot from `p1$data` or `p2$data` (whichever you need), but superimpose the values stored in `y.resp` on your plot, which are the actual response values.  If you don't set the random seed, sjp.glmer will come up with a random configuration of jittered response values every time you invoke it for the same model.

Disclaimer: I do not know enough about your study, data and model to determine if your current modeling approach is sensible. Assuming it is, the code I provided here will make sense. Otherwise, it might not make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this very comprehensive answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it gave you enough background info to enable you to get the plot you want.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I can now confirm if my plots are correct using the manual procedures you provided. I have now 'stolen' the info and made a graph with `ggplot()`!

Comment: That's great! There's nothing like understanding what it is that you are plotting! 