# Logistic regression with "repeated" independent variable

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures

I'm attempting to model my dependent binary variable using only a single continuous independent variable with "duplicate values", but I'm not sure if this counts as a "repeated measures" scenario. I ask because the dependent variable isn't being repeatedly "tested" (because each "outcome" is an independent observation - an individual fish caught in the same net), but the independent variable is the same value for multiple outcomes (the salinity of the water these fish were caught in - this was only recorded once per "net"), so would that count as a "repeated measure"?

Would I just proceed with a simple logistic regression as usual or is there something I should do to account for this? A "1" indicates a fish with an empty stomach.

[image]

I also realize this may be a useless research question. Just because we caught a fish with a full stomach at a location with a certain salinity doesn't mean it ate something under the same conditions. I just wondered how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Isn't your problem similar to predicting gender given height, from a random sample of people (many people will have the same height)? As long as you are comfortable with assuming that the fishes are different specimen (an "independent fishes" assumption), you can model the data with a logistic regression. Since you have the info on catches (or nets) you could perhaps consider net ID as clustering of fishes within catches, for a more complex analysis.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If net ID were a "clustering" variable, what is that analysis called? Just: "logistic regression with a random variable? I'm having trouble finding an example to follow (in R).

Comment: You can find many examples on CV about logistic/binomial generalized linear mixed models (GLMM). [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189115/fitting-a-binomial-glmm-glmer-to-a-response-variable-that-is-a-proportion-or-f) is the first hit I got. If you'd like to jump into the details right away, take a look at this [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html).

Comment: This looks promising as well: https://aaronschlegel.me/predicting-cat-genders-logistic-regression.html

Comment: Yep, there is no lack of resources about GLMMs, though [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) is a framework for ML workflows and not specific to GLMMs.