# GLMM on proportion data based on counts

Tags: generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, spss, glmm, count-data

I am running a GLMM on my small dataset ($n=31$) in a repeated measures study that has $2$ groups and $5$ conditions (conditions are fixed for everyone). I am interested in main effects of group and condition as well as the interaction effect. The dependent variable is derived from two count variables (say response $A$ and response $B$) that are inversely related to each other. I derived the proportion using this formula:
$$
\text{Variable A} - \text{Variable B}/\text{Variable A} + \text{Variable B}
$$

which results in values ranging from $-1$ to $1$. I understand proportion variables are typically bounded between $0$ and $1$, but in this case my negative values are meaningful given the relationship between the two responses. When I try to run the GLMM, many of my cases are excluded because they are negative values.

Does anyone have advice on how to proceed? I am using SPSS which I know isn't ideal but it's what I've got for now! I can provide any other information as needed.

Comment: Hi @Deevy, welcome to CV. 1) "When I try to run the GLMM, many of my cases are excluded because they are negative values." - why is that? If your values are limited -1 to 1, and you feel you have to use a proportion model (which doesn't quite make sense to me), try rescaling it to [0,1]. Then 0.5 (new) will be equivalent to 0 (old)

Comment: 2) If Variable A and Variable B are inversely related, could you just model one of them, and then infer the other?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking at a binomial GLMM. If you are willing to give up your proportion function (which I assume should have two sets of brackets before and after the division), then you can analyse Variable A ~ your predictors, using weights=Variable A + Variable B.

I do not know how to tell this SPSS (to which I have no access), but the weights are just a new column you compute beforehand, "total". On the internet, I found no help/tutorial how to do that in SPSS, but quite a few screenshots that suggest you cannot, which I would find, well, surprising. In ecotoxicology and psychology such data are very common and sometimes called events-per-trial data.

My understanding of your setup: Every participant can pick a number of chocolate (A count) and/or wine gum sweets (B count). You count how many of either they picked. Since some participants pick many sweets and other few, you have a typical binomial problem: "k out of n" were chocolate.

If you go down the "convert to some index" route, you run the risk of weirdly distributed data, even when the original response variable were nicely binomial. I think most post-1990-trained applied statisticians would try to avoid such indices and analyse as close to the original data as possible.

In R (I know I know), your model would be something like:

`summary(lme4::glmer(Acount ~ predictors + (1|ID), family=binomial, weights=total))`

See also [Fitting a binomial GLMM (glmer) to a response variable that is a proportion or fraction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189115/fitting-a-binomial-glmm-glmer-to-a-response-variable-that-is-a-proportion-or-f)