# Binomial glmer with data between 0-1, not count data, not normal proportion

Tags: binomial-distribution, proportion, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have a special case of a binomial glmer and I can't figure out how to properly model it.  I have a random factor `(1|Species)` to account for differences in species.  My response variable consists of "establishment limitation values," which in the literature is calculated as 1 - (# of sites in which seedlings establish / # of sites in which seeds were found).  Values range from 0 - 1.  There are 20 sites in total, so I tried using `weights` set to 20.  But (I assume) since values are not divided by 20, this is not working.  I tried setting `weights` to the # of sites in which seeds were found, but this doesn't work either.  I tried having a column of successes (the number of sites where seedling establishment occurred) and failures (the number of sites where seeds were found but no establishment occurred).  This worked, but I am afraid I am no longer modeling establishment limitations values, but something else, and I don't know how I would explain in my paper that I couldn't model the actual limitation values, which is an important part of my work. I am trying to model the effect of my treatment, seed size and seed dispersal mechanism (Animal vs Wind) on limitation values. For now, excluding dispersal, my formula is:

> model1<-glmer(Est.Limit~Treatment+log(Size)+(1|Species), data=Limitdr.Est, family=binomial, weights=Weight)

I am trying to use the Gauss-Hermite quadrature algorithm (if it's not overdispersed), but I am leaving that out for now until I get this figured out.

How can I model these proportion values?

When I try the above formula, I get this weird outcome:

[image]

Here is a link to my data as an excel file: [Limitdr.est excel file](http://www.filedropper.com/limitdrest_2)

I tried to post as a CSV but I don't have a sufficient reputation for two links.

Let me know if you need any information. I am really looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: "Establishment limitation values:" 1 - $\frac{ \text{# of sites in which seedlings establish}}{\text{# of sites in which seeds were found}}$ = $\frac{ \text{# of sites in which seedlings didn't establish}}{\text{# of sites in which seeds were found}}$ sure looks like a proportion to me, with a "success" being a site in which a seedling didn't establish in terms of the two-column matrix formulation of the binomial model.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you are modeling the establishment limitation, you just made a mistake with the `weights` argument. From R help:

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and hence usually of having the second level).
>
> As a numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given by the weights).
>
> As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures.

Your data clearly fits in the second case, but you have to supply the *total number of cases* to weights.

The following code works for me:

```
model1 <- glmer(Est.Limit ~ Treatment + log(Size) + (1|Species),
                data    = Limitdr.Est,
                family  = "binomial",
                weights = Seed.sites)
```

the result:

```
> summary(model1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Est.Limit ~ Treatment + log(Size) + (1 | Species)
   Data: x
Weights: Seed.sites

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   110.3    117.8    -50.2    100.3       28 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7705 -0.4858 -0.1659  0.6247  2.0272 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Species (Intercept) 4.519    2.126   
Number of obs: 33, groups:  Species, 11

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.9418     0.8370   1.125 0.260523    
TreatmentIsland       0.5172     0.3926   1.317 0.187700    
TreatmentPlantation   1.6060     0.4670   3.439 0.000583 ***
log(Size)            -1.0333     0.3793  -2.724 0.006442 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrtmnI TrtmnP
TrtmntIslnd -0.230              
TrtmntPlntt -0.189  0.466       
log(Size)   -0.479 -0.041 -0.100
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Donlelek, thank you this does help! I am realizing now that the problem I was seeing occurs when I add in the "Succession" category as: `model2 <- glmer(Est.Limit ~ Treatment + log(Size) + Succession +(1|Species),
                data    = Limitdr.Est,
                family  = "binomial",
                weights = Seed.sites)`

Comment: I get this error message: `"Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues`

But this only occurs with Succession included, and the significance of terms are different. Things are fine with Dispersal and every other combo.  I am trying to start from a maximal model and drop non-significant terms to get the best model. Any idea what's wrong with Dispersal?

Comment: Hi @Sylvia, I'm glad that my answer was useful. The problem with `Succession` is that you don't have any failures. If you want you can check yourself by adding one more observation with a failure. Cheers