# How does one deal with lots of 1's when applying the logit function?

Tags: regression, logistic

I have a dataframe containing many feature columns, one of them being `Score`, with values between 0 and 1 (if it helps: it represents the difficulty of a test. The closer to 1, the easier the test). I created an extra column that applies the logit function to each of these values.

The reason why I did this transformation is to do a logistic regression to predict the difficulty. However, many values will be `inf` because in the input there are values such as 0 and 1 (most of them are 1). What do I do with them? Should I apply the logistic function (inverse of logit) to 0 and 1's? Should I just eliminate them?

Comment: You're predicting difficulty, based on difficulty? This is confusing.

Comment: @Gijs I'm sorry, the column with the scores will be deleted, and I will only have the features (test length, test time etc) and this new target column where the logit function was applied. So instead of having a target column "Scores" with values between 0 and 1, I will have a target column with values in \R, but the problem is that there are lots of infinities.

Comment: Logit or logistic regression is in my experience always implemented by a dedicated routine or through some more general routine such as code for generalized linear models. It is not equivalent to regression following a logit transform: in fact for the classic case with a binary outcome with values 0 and 1 logit doesn't yield any finite values at all.  For your case with a more nearly continuous proportion as outcome you should **not** drop any values, but just use an appropriate routine in your unnamed software environment.

Comment: @NickCox I tried various regression models in Python and Google AutoML, using the original column with values between 0 and 1, and I've been told that that was the problem because there was a minimum and maximum value. I had low MAE, RMSE, RMSLE and MAPE, but also a low R^2. That's why I wanted to transform the values.

Comment: Indeed; your response or outcome is bounded and much of the point of logit regression is to respect that and also that it has a particular variance structure, so that for example as the mean approaches 0 or 1 so also the variance approaches zero.  But as said logit regression is not regression on a logit-transfomed outcome. Some people would be happy in practice with a linear model fit to the untransformed data. Otherwise interest in applying a logit model to a continuous proportion is common in practice, but often only discussed in the context of generalized linear models.

Comment: Otherwise put, linear regression on the original data might work not too badly, although the ideal conditions for such a regression are unlikely to be met closely; logit regression using a generalized linear model routine is the alternative. Logit transformation of a continuous proportion is problematic because zeros and ones don't fit that recipe.

Comment: @NickCox thank you, things are more clear right now. If I may ask, do you have any recommendations regarding GLM routines (documentations, sources). I'm very new to this.

Comment: I would start with the book by Dobson and Barnett. I can't recall if they cover your application.

Answer (score 1):

What you seems to want is sometimes called *fractional logistic regression*, there are many Questions on this site, start with [What is the difference between logistic regression and Fractional response regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre)  and search this site.

But very short:

- You should **NOT** transform the scores, use them directly as the outcome variable. Logistic regression will transform implicitly their expectation, not the scores themselves.
- Since your data is not really binomial, the likelihood function is not strictly correct, so use [quasi-likelihood](/questions/tagged/quasi-likelihood)
- With R you would use something like

```r
mod0 <- glm(score ~  ., family=quasibinomial, data=your_df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm working in Python and I found and used this reference: https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/fractional-logit-model-with-python/. But I am getting a negative pseudo R^2, Log-Likelihood, LL-Null and LLR p-value. Is this something to worry about?

Comment: I have no experience with pseudo-R2. Negative loglik is as expected, but a negative p-value is impossible! Better for you to include the results (with some plots) in an edit to the Q