# What are the assumptions of fractional response regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, assumptions, quasi-likelihood

I employed fractional response regression proposed by Wooldridge and Papke for my study as the dependent variable is a proportion (remaining/whole) and is between 0 to 1 (including 0 and 1). I want to know what are the assumptions that must be tested? As such, OLS regression has mainly 3 assumptions such as homoscedasticity, absence of autocorrelation and normality. Similarly, what are the post estimation tests valid for fractional response regression? I used "fracreg" command on Stata to obtain my results.

Comment: You forgot the *most important* assumption of linear regression: Correctly specified model equation.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre