# 2-way Anova on Unequal Group Proportions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, binary-data, sas

I’m working on a dataset collected from a 2-way Anova design (kind of) on binary data. The purpose of the experiment is to explore how different types of email marketing incentives affect customers propensity to buy certain fruits.

- The dependent variable is **Purchase rate** (Binary; if a customer purchased the offered fruit or not)
- Factor A has 3 Levels:

  1. Silent Communication (No incentive offered. To observe customers natural propensity to buy any given fruit.)
  2. Email explaining the benefits of consuming the fruit being offered
  3. Same as 2 but with a 15% discount on the fruit offered
- Factor B has 5 levels. Customers in these groups are incentivized to consume:

  1. Bananas
  2. Apples
  3. Oranges
  4. Kiwis
  5. Fruit of choice (Of the 4 above)

A sample of 150 000 subscribers were randomly allocated to one of the 15 groups with 10k subscribers in each group.

The questions I have are the following:

- Which method or technique should I use to account for the binary response variable?
- When testing the main effect for Factor B, I do not want to test the difference in purchase rates in Table 1 (which is what is computed by default in SAS). Rather, I’m interested in comparing the differences in purchase uplifts between the groups, i.e. the numbers in table 2 highlighted in green.

I’m using SAS and would appreciate to get some guidance and advise on how to handle the two issues described?

[image]

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It's not a course or textbook case, it's a real scenario - only that it in actuality fruits are not the objects studied.

Comment: Do you have individual responses, that is 0/1 or yes/no? In that case, look into logistic regression.  If you have proportions in groups, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre

Answer (score 2):

> Which method or technique should I use to account for the binary response variable?

For a binary response you can use logistic regression. In SAS that would be `PROC LOGISTIC`. You can also use `PROC GLM` with a binomial family and logit link, however `PROC LOGISTIC` is (obviously) designed for fitting logistic models and has extensive options for modelling, binary, and nominal response data, including various link functions, model selection methods, and diagnostic statistics (such as ROC analysis).

> When testing the main effect for Factor B, I do not want to test the difference in purchase rates in Table 1 (which is what is computed by default in SAS). Rather, I’m interested in comparing the differences in purchase uplifts between the groups, i.e. the numbers in table 2 highlighted in green.

If I understand correctly there are several approaches for proportional/fractional outcomes: Tobit (with `PROC QLIM` or `NLMIXED`), NLS (nonlinear least squares, with `PROC NLMIXED`), fractional logit (`PROC NLMIXED` or `GLIMMIX`, beta (PROC `GLIMMIX` or `NLMIXED`, and simplex (`PROC NLMIXED`). If you have negative uplifts, or uplifts greater than 100% this may limit your options.