Modelling Fractional data in R
I have below set of data where response variable is proportional data
dat = structure(list(Y = c(0.0104, 0.01044, 0.00809, 0.00413, 0.00634, 
0.0021, 0.00729, 0.02386, 0.00722, 0.0109, 0.00873, 0.00647, 
0.00611, 0.02342, 0.01818, 0.0176, 0.01865, 0.00546, 0.00515, 
0.02477, 0.00625, 0.01538), X = c(0.01077, 0.01956, 0.02298, 
0.10304, 0.02963, 0.04887, 0.01589, 0.00519, 0.05161, 0.00357, 
0.02279, 0.02733, 0.07581, 0.03643, 0.03257, 0.03324, 0.0509, 
0.05552, 0.08214, 0.01031, 0.08347, 0.02489)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")

In my case, Y is proportional data. So I wanted to fit fractional logistic model on this data as below
> summary(glm("Y ~ X", dat = dat, family = binomial()))

Call:
glm(formula = "Y ~ X", family = binomial(), data = dat)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -4.043      3.381  -1.196    0.232
X            -12.650     88.094  -0.144    0.886

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 0.086252  on 21  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.063149  on 20  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4.4969

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8

Which shows that the variable X is highly insignificant
Which is counter intuitive because, there is significant correlation between Y and X
Now, I fit a simple linear regression, then I get significant X variable
> library(dplyr)
> summary(glm("Z ~ X", dat = dat %>% mutate(Z = log(Y / (1-Y)))))

Call:
glm(formula = "Z ~ X", data = dat %>% mutate(Z = log(Y/(1 - Y))))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -4.1740     0.2074 -20.129 9.55e-15 ***
X           -12.7358     4.4171  -2.883  0.00919 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.3104897)

    Null deviance: 8.7910  on 21  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 6.2098  on 20  degrees of freedom
AIC: 40.605

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

Could you please help me to understand why my first model using glm() fails to show significant X variable?

Relevant  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre

@kjetilbhalvorsen I looked into this post, but does not seem to answer my question. I have a dataset where variables appear to be well correlated. But the glm() estimate fails to address that correlation as provides insignificant estimates. My question what went wrong with my glm fitting?

Your call to glm uses the binomial family incorrectly -- it's not even valid here.  Consult the help page for family for details.  Ultimately, the resolution of your problem likely comes down to what you mean by "proportional data:" how do you make these measurements?

@whuber can you please explain why you say Your call to glm uses the binomial family incorrectly? What is the correct way then? My observations are historical loss information from retail loans hence they are strictly proportional/fractional

Proportions do not have Binomial distributions.  By definition, a Binomial distribution gives probabilities of counts.  The help page shows how this family is intended to be used.

@whuber Yes I know. But there is a concept called Fractional logistic regression where parameters are estimated using Quasi MLE based on Binomial likelihood. That's what I am trying to do here, still not sure what I missed in my implementation. A better pointer would help me

I am unfamiliar with that approach.  But it's hard to see how it would make sense unless you could guarantee all proportions were relative to the same quantity.  And your proportions are consistently small, anyway, so why not use Poisson regression?

@whuber AFAIK Poisson regression does not guarantee that estimates of response variable is bounded by zero and one. In my case, the values of response variable is small, because, as I said, they the losses from retail loans. Since most of the cases loans are collaterized, losses are small for bank although not zero always, nevertheless fractional observations, as loss can't exceed the principal amount of loan. Please note that, the principal amount can be any positive number theoretically

I don't see any information in your data about the principal loan amounts.  You ought to consider modeling your data directly, as (amount, loss) ordered pairs, rather than as fractions.  There's no evident reason why any discrete count distribution, Binomial, Poisson, or otherwise, would be an effective model for losses.  This suggests contemplating a more appropriate model.

@whuber That information is not available. Only the loss percentage information is available for modelling. There is separate modelling for loan principal amount, covered in modelling of EAD i.e. Exposure at default. Regulators like IFRS asks for separate modelling for LGD (Loss Given Default) and EAD. My question and requirement should be viewed more from the Regulatory modelling requirement pov, not a statistical academic modelling - so we need to follow certain way to build model, however that way should not deviate drastically from methodological/conceptual correctness.

I am emphatically not an R expert, but I can't see that you are asking for the fractional character of the outcome to be considered.
Here is the corresponding Stata output.
. fracreg logit Y X, vce(robust)

Iteration 0:  Log pseudolikelihood = -15.370078  
Iteration 1:  Log pseudolikelihood = -1.4565931  
Iteration 2:  Log pseudolikelihood = -1.3448795  
Iteration 3:  Log pseudolikelihood = -1.3426735  
Iteration 4:  Log pseudolikelihood =  -1.342672  
Iteration 5:  Log pseudolikelihood =  -1.342672  

Fractional logistic regression                          Number of obs =     22
                                                        Wald chi2(1)  =  12.91
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0003
Log pseudolikelihood = -1.342672                        Pseudo R2     = 0.0085

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
           Y | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           X |  -12.64962   3.520433    -3.59   0.000    -19.54954   -5.749699
       _cons |  -4.043106   .1699713   -23.79   0.000    -4.376244   -3.709968
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

It naturally is possible but not material to the question to get more decimal places for P-values.
